# Is it safe to use mysql_real_escape_string() for user inputs

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

Recently I am developing little question generation program on PHP. It uses some LaTeX formatted math formulas.

- I had a problem with inserting LaTeX formulas, because no backslash was inserted to MySQL database.
- I've described this issue here :

  [Backslashes are auto-removed while inserting LaTeX formulas to MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300071/backslashes-are-auto-removed-while-inserting-latex-formulas-to-mysql-with-php)
- I found a solution by using mysql_real_escape_string(). But this arises another question.
- If backslashes now could be inserted, is my program vulnerable for sql injections or any other tricky input that users could make?

Comment: I guess you are not using prepared-statements if you are asking this..?!

Comment: use `mysqli_*` function as `mysql_*` deprecated.

Comment: @Naruto, you are right, I'm not.

Comment: @candle You should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is generally designed specifically for sanitising user input and should always be used, as per the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php